# SQL Server - Calculate current row value using previous row value

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have following table and using SQL Server 2008

```
    Tbl_TRNSACTION

 RowNum    Transaction Type        InQty     OutQty     InPrice
    1              IN               20          0           20
    2              IN               50          0           40
    3              OUT              0           10          - 
    4              IN               10          0           30
```

I expect output in following format

If TransType is IN,

then (InQty*InPrice) is added in CumulativeStockVal

and StockRate = (CumulativeStockVal / Balance).

If Transaction Type is OUT,

then (OutQty*previous(StockRate)) is subtracted from CumulativeStockVal.

```
RowNum   TransType InQty   OutQty  Balance  CumulatveStockVal  StockRate

  1        IN      20       0       20      400                20
  2        IN      50       0       70      2400               34.285
  3        OUT     0        10      60      2057.15            34.285
  4        IN      10       0       70      2357.15            33.673
```

Please reply.Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried something? Was there a problem? Just how are the values calculated? Where did those decimals come from? Asking people to write the code for you without showing at least some effort is bad. Asking them to guess what you actually want isn't very polite

Comment: Please post what have you tried so far to get this result.

Comment: Are there additional columns in `Tbl_TRANSACTION`? Tables are inherently *unordered*, so if you want to talk about the "previous" row, we need to now how to define that - which would generally be by using one or more columns to define an order. None are obvious candidates here.

Comment: Insufficient info,ultimately each column is dependent upon each other.revise your question.Secondly which version are you using.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Window Offset Functions combining with AGGREGATE functions.

EDIT: I found you a tut where it is shown very clearly, watch from minute 15.

https://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/en-US/training-courses/querying-microsoft-sql-server-2012-databases-jump-start-8241?l=OZmttuJy_2304984382